Is there a way to map an OUCH outbound message to its corresponding OUCH inbound message without using order token?
Wondering if this is possible as OrderRejected messages may not necessarily contain the order token?
Looked up OUCH documentation and it seems that it doesn't guarantee that outbound messages are in the same sequence as inbound messages.
